# Why we use the word 'compact' for compact spaces?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, compactness

Considering the definition of compactness in either Analysis or Topology books, or its equivalent definitions (i.e. [It] is compact $\Longleftrightarrow\dots$), I couldn't understand why mathematicians have picked the word 'compact' for such a concept in Mathematics.

Even most possible near suggestions from dictionaries either are not appropriate for *any* compact set, or many compact sets don't match it; for example:

1. closely and neatly packed together; dense
2. having all the necessary components or features neatly fitted into a small space

I checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Compact_space) but I couldn't find any note on the terminology. Could someone please tell me (with a reference) the origin of this agreement to use compactness as it is in Mathematics?

Comment: According to German wikipedia, the word was first used by Frechet in 1906 for metric spaces only. In my opinion, the "closely and neatly packed together" is not so much distant from the mathematical definition: compact spaces typically are "small" and have a "finite volume" in some sense...

Comment: @Peter Franek - what about a bounded open ball?

Comment: Would you say that an open ball is "closely and neatly packed together"? :-) An open ball looks very much like the whole of $\Bbb R^n$...

Comment: @PeterFranek : a compact space does not need to be "small". For example, if you consider $Y = \mathbb R ^{\mathbb R}$ "big", then $ X = [0,1]^{[0,1]}$ is compact so "small" but contains a copy of $Y$. And by Tykonov theorem any product of compact is compact, so there is compact space with arbitrary cardinal.

Comment: N.H. I'm aware of Tichonov theorem but always viaualized, for example, $[0,1]^\omega$ as a product of "decreasing intervals" in some sense.. Is there a simple argument that $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ is compact? In the compact-open topology?

Comment: With product topology, I have no idea how to do it without Tychonov, But with countable product it's easy (for example we can put a metric and then show that we can extract  sub-sequence).

Comment: Ok, but this "looks" very different from the space of continuous functions and maybe is not too large either :)

Comment: Yes you're right :) For me my definition of "big" or "small" was the cardinal.  But maybe you had other thing in mind ?

Comment: Yes, though more about "shapes", not cardinality..

Comment: The way I made peace with this term was to think of sequential compactness as meaning that, if you wander around the space forever, you have to keep coming back to the same places -- so the space is small.

Comment: In complete metric spaces, it makes sense because it's equivalent to being closed and totally bounded. I'd say that in general, it makes sense because every open cover can be reduced to finitely many covers, so if it's too "big", then finitely many open sets won't always cut it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fréchet was the one to coin the term, but according to [this page](http://jeff560.tripod.com/c.html) from *Earliest Uses of Some Words in Mathematics*, even he didn't remember why he used it (and also according to that entry, some mathematicians didn't like the term at the time).

But we're stuck with it now!

(I'd like to find another source on this, but I doubt there's much about: even *History of Topology* [doesn't give reasons or any idea of the reception it received](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7iRijkz0rrUC&lpg=PA210&ots=B_ubrM5QvK&pg=PA208#v=onepage&f=false). (As with most histories of mathematics, it seems to have precious little history in it.) )

Comment: Fréchet also coined the term "separable" for metric spaces, and I never saw what was being separated...

Comment: I'm sure this is related to connectedness.

Answer (score 32):

There is already an answer of @Chappers, but I wanted to remark on the word "compact" and why it can be considered suitable for its purpose. Perhaps you will find it relevant.

---

In my opinion, *compact* is a very good term – compact spaces really *are* the spaces that are closely and neatly packed together, however, not in the common literal meaning of the phrase. Perhaps anybody who tries to apply standard intuitions of these concepts is going to be confused, at least I know I was (but thanks to that I was able to arrive at my current intuition $\ddot\smile$).

For example, the real line is **not** compact, but we can adjoin two points to get $\mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty, \infty\}$, and suddenly it **is** compact. But how can adjoining more points make a larger thing small? How can a large (i.e. non-compact) space ever be embedded in a small (i.e. compact) space? Weirder still, the open interval $(0,1)$ is non-compact, despite being apparently much smaller than all the spaces we have so far considered. But once again, we can add two points to get the compact space $[0,1].$ What's going on here?

The point is that despite the difference in apparent length or size (or whatever you wish to call it), the spaces $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty,\infty\}$ are topologically equivalent. Similarly, spaces $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are also topologically equivalent. Furthermore, each of these spaces can be embedded into each other. So we need a notion of closeness that takes that into account. In other words, no ordinary intuition (i.e. the common understanding of two points being close or neatly packed together) will suffice. Compactness solves this problem.

To make my point I will use two conditions equivalent to compactness:

1. A space is compact if every open cover has a finite subcover.
2. A space is compact if every net has a converging subnet ([nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)) are generalizations of sequences).

**On covers:**

Somebody could say: so a compact set has a finite open cover, big issue, $\mathbb{R}$ does have one too! But $(1)$ is much more than that, its *every* open cover has a finite subcover, and the fact that not a single one was left is important. You can think of it in the following way:

Suppose that we have a compact connected space and that you were to tell me which points in your opinion are close to each other and which are far apart. You do this by covering the space with open sets small enough to satisfy your sense of closeness, so that points which are far apart do not belong to the same open set. Yet, for any such cover I can pick a *finite* subcover, which means that the distance in units you care about (i.e. the open sets) between any two points of space is smaller than some constant, hence, close to each other (this is somehow similar to how "almost all" may mean "all but a finite number" despite the finite number being big).

Consider the $(0,1)$ open interval: it may seem small, but you can specify your open sets in a way so that the closer you get to $0$, the father apart your points will be (in terms of number of open sets needed to connect them). On the other hand take the the extended real line, you may go on with bigger and bigger numbers, but you have to finally fall into the open set containing $+\infty$, and you will do it in a finite number of steps.

**On nets:**

The nets are a generalization of sequences, so make this more approachable, let me describe this in terms of sequences, just remember that [sequential compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space) and compactness are not equivalent (although they are for metric spaces).

Consider a compact space and a sequence of elements of it. You could imagine walking around and visiting different places of that space. We know that it has a convergent subsequence, so, in other words, there has to be a place the neighborhood of which you visit infinitely many times. That means, if you walk long enough, you will have to come back to some neighborhood you have already been to. Such a space has to be rather small, right?

On the other hand, if you were to consider a sequence that does not have any converging subsequence, e.g. $1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots$, then you can go on and on, but the space is not compact anymore - it is not "closely and neatly packed together". Similarly with $(0,1)$, you can pick the neighborhoods (cover) and a specific pattern of walking (dependent on the neighborhoods) so that you won't visit any neighborhood twice. Such a space is not small, but neither it is compact.

Putting this in terms of nets instead of sequences (which means that we are doing steps along arbitrary directed set, not just the natural numbers, for example you could make infinitely many infinitely small steps) might be confusing, but I think it still gives some intuition why you can think of compact spaces are "closely and neatly packed together".

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Woah, the "on covers" bit was great!

Comment: I've put this on my list of favorite answers, in my profile. I think the intuition you provide is just great. Having reread the introductory paragraphs, however, I think the "general handwaiving" section could do with a bit of, let us say, *perfecting.*

Comment: @goblin Thank you for your kind comments. In what way would you improve the intro section?

Comment: Okay, I've done a big edit of your intro section, but I'm a bit concerned that I may have accidentally deleted some of the ideas/intuitions you put into it. Perhaps have a read over it, and then do a further edit to make sure the points you want to make are still being made.

Comment: @goblin I altered small bits to match my preferences, but your edits made it much easier to read, and you did preserve all the important things. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Good teamwork :)