# What are good resources to learn about convergence spaces?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, category-theory, book-recommendation, online-resources

What are good resources (books, lecture notes, introductory papers, ...) to learn about [convergence spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convergence+space)?

I read [in an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373022/intuitive-approach-to-topology/2373188#2373188) to a recent question the following:

> There's still a subtle issue. If you try to axiomatize topological spaces via filter convergence, you wind up with a significantly more general notion called a [convergence space](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convergence+space). Convergence spaces are really nice, and personally I wish people would start treating them as the basic objects of interest in general topology, and treat topological spaces as a mere special case. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find an elementary introduction to such things that I can link you to, so you'll have to learn things the classical way until you're ready to go off on your own.

This sounds quite intriguing, so I thought it might be reasonable to ask where to look if I decide to learn a bit more about convergence spaces.

Comment: I was not sure whether to add the tag (category-theory) or not - I added it mainly because most often when I see convergence spaces, they are introduced as a category (and quite often they appear in texts about category theory).

Answer (score 6):

There is a new (2016) textbook which covers convergence spaces and related concepts:

- ["Continuity Theory" by Louis Nel](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319311586)

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions:

- [Basic Properties of Filter Convergence spaces](https://www.bioinf.uni-leipzig.de/~studla/Publications/PREPRINTS/01-pfs-007-subl1.pdf)
- [On the theory of convergence spaces](https://scholar.najah.edu/sites/default/files/Raed%20Shqair.pdf)

and references therein. I'm also quite interested to learn about new resources, especially ones with lots of (worked) examples to get a feel for the difference between, say, a pseudotopological and a pretopological convergence, etc.

The motivation for their study often seems category-theoretical (convergence spaces are Cartesian closed, e.g.). I would also like to see a good list of open problems, e.g.

[This page](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Topological_structures) offers a general overview of "topology-like" classes of spaces, and I once read parts of the book: "G. Preuss, "Topological structures—An approach to categorical topology" , Reidel (1988)", which mostly talks about category constructions (like initial and final structures), it seems appropriate in view of your tags.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, there is:

- "Problems in the Theory of Convergence Spaces" by D. R. Patten
- "Grundstrukturen der Analysis" I & II by W. Gähler, if you understand German

Also "Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations" by E. Schechter deals briefly with convergence spaces (and pretopological spaces).

Answer (score 2):

I think the book below is trying to do exactly what you are looking for:

> Szymon Dolecki and Frédéric Mynard, [**Convergence Foundations of Topology**](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/9012#t=aboutBook). World Scientific Publishing. 2016. DOI:10.1142/9012

There's also this upcoming one, somewhat in the same spirit:

> Szymon Dolecki, **[A Royal Road to Topology](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/12154#t=aboutBook)**. World Scientific Publishing. 2023. DOI:10.1142/12154

Answer (score 1):

The one I'm reading is [Convergence Structures and Applications to Functional Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1402005660) by R. Beattie and Heinz-Peter Butzmann.

I've liked it so far, and starts with Convergence Spaces right away. Worth taking a look, specially for the ones that like Analysis.